# Get a dictionary from iPhone on Watch prior to launching the phone app - WC

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchconnectivity

I've faced an issue while trying to synchronise iPhone app and WatchKit app.
The thing is - my WatchKit app `tableView` is appended by the data array from iPhone.

I'm using interactive messaging from Watch Connectivity framework

Establishing session

```
    if(WCSession.isSupported()){
        self.session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        self.session.delegate = self
        self.session.activateSession()
    }
```

sending message to WatchKit app

```
    do {
        let dataDict = ["data": dictionary1]
        try WCSession.defaultSession().updateApplicationContext(dataDict)
    }

    catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

and this is how i receive the message on the Watch

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in


        if let retrievedArray1 = applicationContext["data"] as? [Int : Bool] {

            self.arrayOnWatch = retrievedArray1

        }
    }}
```

It works well with one exception - i cannot get the data array UNTIL i launch the app on the iPhone, which isn't a solution in my case.

Any ideas on how to transfer and receive the message without opening the actual phone app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the application context does not work for your case, because it needs the iPhone app to actively set the application context.

You can use WatchKit's `sendMessage` to let the watch ask the iPhone app for data.

In your **ExtensionDelegate** after activating the connection send a message to the iPhone app:

```
if WCSession.defaultSession().reachable {
    let messageDict = ["message": "hello iPhone!"]
    WCSession.defaultSession().sendMessage(messageDict, replyHandler: { (replyDict) -> Void in
        print(replyDict)
        }, errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
        print(error)
    }
}
```

This will wake up your iPhone app in the background if the iPhone app is not running.

In your iPhone app's **AppDelegate** implement the corresponding WCSessionDelegate method (after activating the session in `didFinishLauncingWithOptions:`

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void) {
    replyHandler(["message": "Hello Watch!"])
}
```

Just send your data instead of "Hello Watch!" and your watch will have the data even if the iPhone app is not running.

Comment: That was very helpful, Thanks!